# React-Native BackHandler always closes App in Android (hardware back)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm building a App with `react-native v0.44.0` using `redux v5.0.5` and `react-navigation v1.0.0-beta.11`. The routing is done with nested navigators, one main StackNavigator and DrawerNavigator.
I'm handling all navigation events in a navigation reducer, also the hardware back press on Android using BackHandler. Now comes the weird part (for me), I've implemented the BackHandler event handlers like so:

```
import { BackHandler, Modal, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';    
import { HARDWARE_BACK_PRESS } from '../helpers/NavTypes';

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleBack = this.handleBack.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener(HARDWARE_BACK_PRESS, this.handleBack);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener(HARDWARE_BACK_PRESS, this.handleBack);
}

handleBack() {
  const navAction = NavigationActions.back();

  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navAction);
  return true;
}
```

In my navigation reducer I'm handling the `Navigation/BACK` action type and keep track of my state. Now, when I'm pressing the hardware back button on my Android device or in the emulator, I can see thanks to `redux-logger` and the React Native debugger that the navigation action is dispatched correctly and the previous shown screen appears, but the app closes anyway. This happens also when I alter the `handleBack` method to something like this:

```
handleBack() {
  return true;
}
```

Every time the hardware back button is pressed, the App still closes. I did some step-debugging in`node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/BackHandler.android.js`, inside of `RCTDeviceEventEmitter.addListener` I can see that my event listeners are registered and `invokeDefault` is set to `true` in the loop. `addListener` is exited but the App still closes. Does anyone know if there is some point there react-navigation and redux are overriding the behaviour of the hardware back button at some top level I'm not aware of?
I've setup a second plain RN project without react-navigation and redux, implementing the same BackHandler event listeners (also returning true) and the app won't close. So, right now this leaves me a bit puzzled.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, did it work for you?

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix To be onest, in that project we updated to a newer `react-native`, `redux` and `react-navigation` version and everything works as aspected now. But I've created a fork of that project with the old modules where the issue still exists, as far as I've some spare time, I try to figure out what's wrong with that implementation.

Comment: my issue got resolved by solution given in this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15497 by Victoriayangx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-navigation and I also handle the os back button. It works fine for me.
May be you can try this out.  Note that handleBack must return true if you are performing any other task than closing the app. If not it will close the app immediately.

```
 componentWillMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener(HARDWARE_BACK_PRESS, () => { return this.handleBack.bind(this)() });
}
```

Comment: Hi @csath, thank you for your answer. But that didn't change anything. As I said, I can even change `handleBack` to always return `true` and the App will still close. I've no idea where I can hook in the process to explore the problem more deeper. Right now I'm reading the adb logcat logs to see if there is any hint where that "overruling" hardware back press comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, returning `true` wouldn't update. Running `react-native run-android` again after the changes fixed the problem for me.